How to install Expo into bare ReactNative with altered AppDelegate
In my application, I use a package that requires some native config in AppDelegate files and it is not compatible with the RCTAppDelegate so I had to copy over the method's definition and implementation manually. Doing so forbids me from using the EXAppDelegateWrapper as mentioned in the documentation.
This is my AppDelegate.h file:
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <ExponeaRNAppDelegate.h>

@class RCTBridge;
@protocol RCTBridgeDelegate;
@protocol RCTComponentViewProtocol;
@class RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UISceneDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RCTBridge *bridge;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *moduleName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *initialProps;

- (RCTBridge *)createBridgeWithDelegate:(id<RCTBridgeDelegate>)delegate launchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;

- (UIView *)createRootViewWithBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
                          moduleName:(NSString *)moduleName
                           initProps:(NSDictionary *)initProps;

- (UIViewController *)createRootViewController;

- (void)setRootView:(UIView *)rootView toRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;

- (BOOL)runtimeSchedulerEnabled;

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
@property (nonatomic, strong) RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter *bridgeAdapter;

- (NSDictionary<NSString *, Class<RCTComponentViewProtocol>> *)thirdPartyFabricComponents;

- (BOOL)turboModuleEnabled;

- (BOOL)fabricEnabled;

- (BOOL)bridgelessEnabled;

- (NSURL *)getBundleURL;

#endif
@end

How can I install expo modules? I tried copying over the methods from EXReactDelegateWrapper, but when I run the app and try to use the Expo-image module for example, it throws this errors:
ERROR  Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoImage', js engine: hermes
ERROR  TypeError: TaskQueue: Error with task : Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined
I tried copying over methods from the EXReactDelegateWrapper
